# How can the time value portion of an option be higher than 100%?

Tags: option-pricing, american-options, interactive-brokers, time

Here's a screenshot from InteractiveBrokers TWS for the near-the-money put and call on the ES Dec '15 Future:

[image: ES future options ATM]

The absolute value of the [time value](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/16973/calculating-time-value-of-an-option), 9.50, makes sense. But why is the percentage value over 180%, regardless of [moneyness](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/2685/how-does-an-options-time-value-depend-on-moneyness)?

Comment: Don't IB provide any documentation on their fields?

Comment: IB's TWS is very nice software, with a lot of features, but there are glitches and bugs sometimes (in my experience). This may be one of those.